# how to access localhost:4200 (Angular App) on Big Sur from another computer within the same lan?

Tags: angular, firewall, lan, macos-big-sur, linksys

[screencapture : linksys port-forward table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yJ7T.png)

My case is listed as below :

- The client computer and the server computer are on the same lan where the wifi router is : linksys model#ea6200
- The client computer can ping the server computer(where the server's OS is Big Sur 11.4 and its IP is 192.168.1.149)
- The server is already listening to http://localhost:4200 , which is an Angular application .
- But , when I type http://192.168.1.149:4200 in the client's browser, the site can’t be reached from the  client's computer .
- I have checked that the Big Sur's firewall is off.

My Question is :

1. What else should be further set so that the site on the server computer can be reached from the  client's computer ?
2. Should I consider to make some configuration on the linksys port
   forwarding policy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers from "NSteinbusch @ https://discord.davidbombal.com/ " :

- this is an Angular issue rather than networking issue ;
- by default angular only listen on local interface 127.0.0.1 ;
- By using the following command on the command prompt `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`, instead of simply typing `ng serve` to start the app, the client PC should be able to reach the Angular app of the server at http://192.168.1.149:4200/
- By this method, the server will listen to all available interface, so your Ethernet NIC or Wi-Fi NIC as well.